# How do I change the focal length of a camera with python?

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I am importing a VRML file using Blender command line. I need to change the focal length of the camera using the command line.

How can I do that? I cannot find Python api for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in `bpy.data.cameras['`*`name of your camera object`*`'].lens`, or `camera.angle` (thanks [@ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14745/how-do-i-change-the-focal-length-of-a-camera-with-python/14749?noredirect=1#comment20320_14749)).

Note that you must have a camera in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it ..

We can get the focal length by using `bpy.data.cameras.values()[0].lens`. We can set this value as well.

Comment: `bpy.data.cameras.values()[0].lens` is better written as `bpy.data.cameras[0].lens`