# Unable to change focal length of camera using python

Tags: python, camera

I want to add a camera from my scene using python. I followed [the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117325/how-do-i-set-my-camera-rotation-with-python) and it created the camera but I am not being able to change the focal length. I even tried using [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14745/how-do-i-change-the-focal-length-of-a-camera-with-python) but the focal length remains the same (as default = 50).

```
def setupCamera(scene, c):
    pi = math.pi

    scene.camera.rotation_euler[0] = c[0] * (pi / 180.0)
    scene.camera.rotation_euler[1] = c[1] * (pi / 180.0)
    scene.camera.rotation_euler[2] = c[2] * (pi / 180.0)

    scene.camera.location.x = c[3]
    scene.camera.location.y = c[4]
    scene.camera.location.z = c[5]

    return

scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
config = list([69.1, 1.6, 38.9, 7.22, -6.94, 4.95])
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
cam.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
scene.camera = cam

# Changing focal length
bpy.data.cameras[0].lens = 9.0

setupCamera(scene=scene, c=config)
```

I have the links to answer but I cannot figure out why the focal length is not being changed to 9.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying the correct camera. When you call `bpy.ops.object.camera_add()`, the newly created camera becomes the new active object. You can get it with `bpy.context.object`. You need to modify *that* camera.

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
cam = bpy.context.object
cam.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
scene.camera = cam

# Changing focal length
cam.data.lens = 9.0

config = [69.1, 1.6, 38.9, 7.22, -6.94, 4.95]
setupCamera(scene=scene, c=config)
```